# How to convert HTML tags to RTF or any rich format text from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, conversion, html, sed

How can I convert HTML tags to rtRTF or any rich format text using `sed` or any linux command-line tool?

I've achieved to strip them with `sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'`, but I need the `<b>hi</b>` to convert to `**hi**`.

Answer (score 4):

[html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text#readme) is a command-line tool that converts HTML to Markdown.

You will most probably get very frustrated trying to use `sed` to do this without error. The reason is touched upon in a [legendary SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348). In very basic cases it *might* work, but it *will* come back to haunt you of you make it a habit, so learn how to do it correctly directly instead. Using a ready tool such as html2text is a lot better than trying to regex it out by hand.